# appending and removing dynamic php menus with json

Tags: jquery, json

I am using the following code to append a dynamic php menu to a table cell.

```
$("input:radio[id='l1_allowed_0']").click(function() {  

$(".l1_p1_action").append('<select name="pathway_actions[]" id="pathway_actions">' );

$.getJSON('../scripts/get_pathway_actions.php', function (json) {
$("#pathway_actions").empty();
$.each(json, function () {
$("#pathway_actions").append(new Option(this.action));
});  
});
});
```

What would I use to remove the menu from $(".l1_p1_action"), say in:

```
$("input:radio[id='l1_allowed_1']").click(function() {  


});
```

**EDIT**

I have changed the code to create menus with unique IDs.  Two problems:

The remove isn't working and a new menu gets appended each time the radio button gets clicked:

```
$("input:radio[id='l1_allowed_0']").click(function() {  

$(".l1_p2_actions").remove();
$(".l1_p3_actions").remove();
$(".l1_p4_actions").remove();

$(".l1_p1_action").append('<select name="l1_p1_actions" id="l1_p1_actions">' );

$.getJSON('../scripts/get_pathway_actions.php', function (json) {
$("#l1_p1_actions").empty();
$.each(json, function () {
$("#l1_p1_actions").append(new Option(this.action));
});  
});
});



$("input:radio[id='l1_allowed_1']").click(function() {  

$(".l1_p1_actions").remove();
$(".l1_p3_actions").remove();
$(".l1_p4_actions").remove();

$(".l1_p2_action").append('<select name="l1_p2_actions" id="l1_p2_actions">' );

$.getJSON('../scripts/get_pathway_actions.php', function (json) {
$("#l1_p2_actions").empty();
$.each(json, function () {
$("#l1_p2_actions").append(new Option(this.action));
});  
});
});
```

Aargh, wrong selector on the remove lines...  changed to the following and the removes are working now.

```
$("#l1_p2_actions").remove();
$("#l1_p3_actions").remove();
$("#l1_p4_actions").remove();
```

Still have the problem with extra empty menus being appended to a cell if the radio button is clicked multiple times...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the remove function and specify the id of the element to be removed, as the id *should* be unique on the page:

```
$("input:radio[id='l1_allowed_1']").click(function() {
    $("#pathway_actions").remove();
});
```

Comment: The table contains a number of rows with a radio group button in each row.  When a radio button is clicked, the menu gets appended to the last cell in that row.  The cells have the class l1_p1_action, l1_p2_action etc.  So I need to specifically remove the menu from the other cell if the current cell gets the menu appended.  Hope that's clear...

Comment: Another option, if the select is only ever to appear in one row at a time, is to create the select as an object, then use a combination of remove and append to move the select between rows.